# What is the pattern in this puzzle?

Tags: pattern

I can't figure this puzzle out. Could you help me with the pattern, please?

Thank you in advance.

[image: Missing diagram]

Comment: Could you also include the source of where you found this question?

Comment: Hi, the source is: [test](http://psymed.info/iq_test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it is option 1 as that is the only one with an even number of blue squares and an odd number of white squares

(consistent with the four preceding it)